# Authenticating user before profile is activated in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to design a signup process where a user completes the signup form, receives an email detailing the next step(s) forward. The user shall remain as an inactive user until I manually login as an admin and activate the user's profile.

This is what I have in my `views.py` (`teachers.py`):

```
class TeacherSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = TeacherSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'teacher'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form, request):
        user = form.save()
        # user.set_password(form.cl)
        login(self.request, user)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        htmly = get_template('classroom/teachers/email.html')
        d = {'username': username}
        subject, from_email, to = 'Welcome to GradientBoost', 'emmanuel@thegradientboost.com', email
        html_content = htmly.render(d)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
        msg.send()
        if request.user.is_activated:
            return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
        else:
            return redirect('teachers:notyet')

models.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and `classroom.py` (views for the home page, about page etc):

```
#redirects after signup
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_activated:
        if request.user.is_teacher:
            return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
        elif request.user.is_student:
            return redirect('students:app-student-dashboard')
    return render(request, 'classroom/home.html')
#about us page
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'classroom/about-us.html')
#courses page
def courses(request):
    return render(request, 'classroom/courses.html')
#course details
def course_details(request):
    return render(request, 'classroom/course-details.html')
```

However, when I attempt to signup I get the error message:

```
TypeError at /accounts/signup/teacher/
form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: form_valid() function should be `def form_valid(self, form)`

Comment: @Kurohige should I leave out the if request.user.is_activated part because if I do then the user would be automatically redirected to their profile page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by Kurohige, your `form_valid` method have [incorrect signature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid). [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) is the example of correct usage for class based views.

Also, you do not need the request as function argument and you already using the correct option `login(self.request, user)`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    login(self.request, user)
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    htmly = get_template('classroom/teachers/email.html')
    d = {'username': username}
    subject, from_email, to = 'Welcome to GradientBoost', 'emmanuel@thegradientboost.com', email
    html_content = htmly.render(d)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
    msg.send()
    if request.user.is_activated:
        return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
    return redirect('teachers:notyet')
```

Comment: Thanks, so should I remove the redirect to the profile page, i only want the user to be redirected to their profile page if they have been acitvated

Comment: because If i remove the redirect I get the error message  didn't return an HttpResponse object and If I leave the redirect the signup is automatically redirected to the profile page- which isn't the desired action

Comment: Why you asked about redirect removal? At first glance you need to replace each `request` with `self.request` inside `is_valid` method and remove request from method arguments.

Comment: @Emm I update the answer with code for `form_valid` method.

Comment: now getting the error message: name 'request' is not defined